# How to loop thru child nodes under a key base on condition

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase DB structure below and encountered some difficulty in access to the values in the child node base on conditions. below are my code and the db structure in which there are many `cartId` which belong to a `userid`.

```
    MasterCart
      |
      |-- AdminCart
            |
            |- CurrentDate (in string)
                 |
                 |-cartId(1)           
                 |   |
                 |   |- userId(1)      
                 |   |   |
                 |   |   |- username
                 |   |   |- paymentId
                 |   |   |- total
                 |   |   |
                 |   |   |- cartItems     
                 |   |       |
                 |   |       |-ProductId(1)
                 |   |       |  |
                 |   |       |  |- productname
                 |   |       |  |- productPrice
                 |   |       |  |- quantity
                 |   |       |  |- productDescription
                 |   |       |
                 |   |       |-productId(2)
                 |   |
                 |   |- userId(2)
                 |   | ....
                 |
                 |
                 |-cartId(2)
                      |
                      |-userId(2.1)
                          |
                          |....
```

problems:

1. How to access the values in `cartItems` if the following conditions met:

if `paymentId` is not empty

How to handle this :

how to get and loop thru cartItems as this Json data.

this is my code:

```
 var Root = firebase.database().ref();
 const cartRef = Root.child('MasterCart').child('AdminCart').child('2020-11-19')

 cartRef.once('value',function(snapshot){
     
      if (snapshot.exists()) {

           snapshot.forEach(function(spshot2) {   
   
                 var val = data.val();
                 var payId = val.paymentId;
                 var  ttl = val.total;

                 if(payId) {

                  // how to get and loop thru cartItems

                       .......  

                     content += '<tr>';
                     content += '<td>' + productname + '</td>';
                     content += '<td>' + productprice  + '</td>';
                     content += '<td>' + quantity + '</td>';
                     content += '</tr>';

                     });

                     $('#ex-table').append(content);
                 }
          });

       }

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

```js
// for brevity rest of your code is avoided here

if(payId) {
    cartRef.child('cartItems').once('value', snapshot3 => {
        // omitting existence check for brevity
        snapshot3.forEach(cartItem => {
            const cartItemVal = cartItem.val();
            // now add this item to your DOM
        });
    });
}
// rest of your code
```

Comment: Are there any errors? Does the snapshot exists (i.e., snapshot3)?